# <iframe> is loading the page indefinitely

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have embedded a page in a `<iframe>` as follows :

```
<iframe id = 'iframeid'
        src="/qgis/index.html"
        scrolling="no"
        frameborder="0"
        style="height: 100vh;
               width: 100%"
        onload="on_load(this)">
</iframe>
```

And here is the on_load function called once the iframe is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function on_load(iframe) {
try {
  var lat = -0.017;
  var lng = 0.015;
  var zoom = 16;

  var map = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.map;

  map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
  } catch (e) {
    // This can happen if the src of the iframe is
    // on another domain
    alert('exception: ' + e);
  }
}
</script>
```

My problem is that the `<iframe>` enters a loop and the page is loaded once again, inside the `<iframe>`, and it goes like this indefinitely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to use jQuery you might try to change your function "onload" with :

```
$('document').ready(function(){

try {
  var lat = -0.017;
  var lng = 0.015;
  var zoom = 16;

  var map = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.map;

  map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
  } catch (e) {
    // This can happen if the src of the iframe is
    // on another domain
    alert('exception: ' + e);
  }

});
```

Because I'm wondering if your script is triggering the onload while it's still not ready.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and added a line befor your javascript

try it :

```
<iframe id = 'iframeid'
    src="home.html"
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="0"
    style="height: 100vh;
           width: 100%"
    onload="on_load(this)">
</iframe>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function on_load(iframe) {
try {
var lat = -0.017;
var lng = 0.015;
var zoom = 16;

var map = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentWindow.map;

 map.setView([lat, lng], zoom);
} catch (e) {
// This can happen if the src of the iframe is
// on another domain
alert('exception: ' + e);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing changed : The iframe keeps on loading the page inside again and again.